# Is it possible to apply sound filters in Flash?

Tags: audio, actionscript, filter, actionscript-2, flash-cs6

So basically i have a soundboard made in Flash CS5, is it possible to alternate the sound of the library's audio files with using Flash only? Like make the clips sound deeper or faster, thats the point. But if it's not pissbile

Comment: Do you mean you want to achieve your goal by ActionScript 3 programming?

Comment: I meant Action Script 2, but i guess the tag with it got deleted or something. But if it's not possible in AS2, is it in AS3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it in AS2. But yes, you can change the pitch and playback speed of a sound in AS3. In fact you can do more than that (search for Audiotool) but this demonstrates how it is done:
http://plasticsturgeon.com/2012/05/changing-the-pitch-of-a-looped-sound-at-runtime-with-actionscript/

And in case my blog goes down or something, here is the relevant class that changes the pitch of a sound.:

```
    package sound
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.SampleDataEvent;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.media.SoundTransform;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

/**
 * @author Andre Michelle (andr...@gmail.com)
     * Modified by Zach Foley aka The Plastic Sturgeon
 */
public class MP3Pitch
{
    private const BLOCK_SIZE: int = 3072;

    private var _mp3: Sound;
    private var _sound: Sound;

    private var _target: ByteArray;

    private var _position: Number;
    private var _rate: Number;
    private var repeat:SoundChannel;
    private var _volume:Number = 1;
    private var byteArray:ByteArray;

            // Pass in your looped Sound
    public function MP3Pitch( pitchedSound: Sound)
    {
        _target = new ByteArray();
        _mp3 =  pitchedSound;

        _position = 0.0;
        _rate = 0.0;

        _sound = new Sound();
        _sound.addEventListener( SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, sampleData );
        repeat = _sound.play();
    }

    public function get rate(): Number
    {
        return _rate;
    }

            // Also added a handy volume setter
    public function set volume( value: Number ): void
    {
        _volume = value;
        repeat.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(_volume);
    }

            // use this to set the pitch of your sound
    public function set rate( value: Number ): void
    {
        if( value < 0.0 )
            value = 0;

        _rate =  value;
    }

    private function sampleData( event: SampleDataEvent ): void
    {
        //-- REUSE INSTEAD OF RECREATION
        _target.position = 0;

        //-- SHORTCUT
        var data: ByteArray = event.data;

        var scaledBlockSize: Number = BLOCK_SIZE * _rate;
        var positionInt: int = _position;
        var alpha: Number = _position - positionInt;

        var positionTargetNum: Number = alpha;
        var positionTargetInt: int = -1;

        //-- COMPUTE NUMBER OF SAMPLES NEED TO PROCESS BLOCK (+2 FOR INTERPOLATION)
        var need: int = Math.ceil( scaledBlockSize ) + 2;

        //-- EXTRACT SAMPLES
        var read: int = _mp3.extract( _target, need, positionInt );

        var n: int = read == need ? BLOCK_SIZE : read / _rate;

        var l0: Number;
        var r0: Number;
        var l1: Number;
        var r1: Number;

        for( var i: int = 0 ; i < n ; ++i )
        {
            //-- AVOID READING EQUAL SAMPLES, IF RATE < 1.0
            if( int( positionTargetNum ) != positionTargetInt )
            {
                positionTargetInt = positionTargetNum;

                //-- SET TARGET READ POSITION
                _target.position = positionTargetInt << 3;                      //-- READ TWO STEREO SAMPLES FOR LINEAR INTERPOLATION                   l0 = _target.readFloat();                   r0 = _target.readFloat();                   l1 = _target.readFloat();                   r1 = _target.readFloat();               }                               //-- WRITE INTERPOLATED AMPLITUDES INTO STREAM              data.writeFloat( l0 + alpha * ( l1 - l0 ) );                data.writeFloat( r0 + alpha * ( r1 - r0 ) );                                //-- INCREASE TARGET POSITION               positionTargetNum += _rate;                                 //-- INCREASE FRACTION AND CLAMP BETWEEN 0 AND 1                alpha += _rate;                 while( alpha &gt;= 1.0 ) --alpha;
        }

        //-- FILL REST OF STREAM WITH ZEROs
        if( i < BLOCK_SIZE )
        {
            while( i < BLOCK_SIZE )                 {                   data.writeFloat( 0.0 );                     data.writeFloat( 0.0 );                                         ++i;                }           }           //-- INCREASE SOUND POSITION            _position += scaledBlockSize;                        // My little addition here:            if (_position &gt; _mp3.length * 44.1) {
            _position = 0;
            _target.position = 0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It does work. Check your code for errors. I've used this in several projects. For example - I use it in this game to change the engine pitch as the hover-car accelerates. http://www.welcometorecall.com/game/recallrush/

Comment: I did eventually get it working. I don't recall what the problem was, it might've been the sound format. But regardless I did manage to get it working. Cheers! (Also, you might want to edit the source code format as the "<" character was translated to "&lt;")

Comment: Thanks - I fixed the escaped characters. Now it says "<" instead of "&lt;" -  that might have been the problem if you copied the code from this page instead of the blog entry.

Comment: Okay, so I reproduced the issue with the class. If I render an mp3 that isn't 320KBPs, the mp3 gets looped too early. Do I need to adjust the block size?

Comment: I fixed it by modifying the class.      I moved the _position = _skip_bytes_at_start; to that if i<BLOCK_SIZE (after the while block) since that seemed to only fire when end of track was reached.